# Mysql Distinct gives a syntax error - remove duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql

With some help from someone here on Stackoverflow i almost got to the point where the query is perfect. I need some little help adjusting the query to fit my needs, and i hope someone could help me out again.

Here's the case, i have the following 2 tables :

```
Tweet
```

and

```
Tweet_tags
```

Every tweet has a tag, and a tweet can have more of the same tags. I want to count how many tweets have the same tag within a time span of week since the tweet was posted.

Here is the query as it is now :

```
SELECT t.id
     , s.tag
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM twitter.tweet_tags r
           JOIN twitter.tweet q
             ON q.id = r.tweet_id
          WHERE r.tag = s.tag
            AND q.date >= t.date
            AND q.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
       ) AS cnt
  FROM twitter.tweet t 
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags s 
    ON s.tweet_id = t.id
 ORDER
    BY cnt DESC
```

The results of this query are :

```
  | ID |     Tag      | Cnt |
-------------------------------
  | 1  |  Testtag     | 2   |
  | 2  |  Testtag     | 1   |
  | 3  |  tweettag3   | 1   |
  | 4  |  tweettag2   | 1   |
```

I have the testtag 2 times in my database, so the first result is correct, tweettag3 and tweettag2 are in my database 1 time so thats good as well, but these will probably also show multiple results when i add them again. I tried using `DISTINCT` on `s.tag` to get rid of the duplicate result, however this gives me a syntax error.

So how i want it to be is :

```
  | ID |     Tag      | Cnt |
-------------------------------
  | 1  |  Testtag     | 2   |
  | 2  |  tweettag3   | 1   |
  | 3  |  tweettag2   | 1   |
```

Could someone please help me out on this? If you need more information please say so!

Thanks !!

Edit :

This is how the tables look:

```
Tweet
---------------
ID
Message
users_id
Date

Tweet_tags
---------------
id
tag
tweet_id
```

Comment: what is the table structure of both tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `select distinct`, so the query would be:

```
SELECT distinct s.tag
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM twitter.tweet_tags r
           JOIN twitter.tweet q
             ON q.id = r.tweet_id
          WHERE r.tag = s.tag
            AND q.date >= t.date
            AND q.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
       ) AS cnt
  FROM twitter.tweet t 
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags s 
    ON s.tweet_id = t.id
 ORDER
    BY cnt DESC
```

Just remove the id field from the select.

If you want an id, then you can use the MySQL feature of hidden columns to have:

```
select t.id, s.tag, . . .

group by tag
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this is giving me exactly the same result :( even with using distinct it is showing testtag twice

Comment: @user1362916 . . . It would probably give you a different result, now that I put back in the `distinct` that I accidentally removed on an earlier edit.  Also, the `group by` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    t.id , 
    s.tag , 
    s.count
FROM twitter.tweet t 
JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) as count,
        tweet_id,
        tag
    FROM tweet_tags
    GROUP BY tweet_id
) as s ON s.tweet_id = t.id
        AND  t.tag = s.tag
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: What about the 7 day interval?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 's.tag' in 'field list'  is what im getting

Comment: Yes when using in ON we should select in the subquery all the columns we are going to use in joining

Comment: Could you provide me with an example? Sounds like magic to me sorry

Comment: without your table structure i can't say anything

Comment: have you checked the query again?

Comment: yes, its now saying : #1054 - Unknown column 'r.tag' in 'on clause'